# Start multiple JavaScript files and wait for them to finish

Tags: batch-file

I am building a program that outputs a batch file. In this batch file there are some links to JavaScript files, which are then supposed to run within photoshop.

Most of it works, but I just want the next JavaScript to run when the previous one is finished! Is this possible?

Comment: `start /wait` may help, see `start /?`

Comment: Yes, this is possible. How do you call the JS scripts?

Comment: i used:
start /wait "" "PATH TO PHOTOSHOP"  "PATH_TO_JS_FILE"

Comment: I have an answer, it was the /wait part.

Comment: you may also use the `/d "path"` switch of `start` command, it simplifies things a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible using `start` with the `/wait` flag, telling the system to wait to finish a command before processing the next command. Run each file with:

```
start "" /wait node something.js [arguments]
```

It is suggested for you, to read the output of `start /?` carefully in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @JoeyCooijmans, it usually is when you read the help file for the command you are using.